# How to extract strings from plist files for translation (localization)?

Tags: iphone, localization, plist, translation, extract

I need to prepare list of strings for translation of my iPhone application.
I have extracted strings from ***.m files using genstring** and **from the XIB files using ibtool** command.

But I have also **lots of texts to translate in plist files** (String field types enclosed in **string** tag).
Is there a nice bash script / command to extract those strings into a flat txt file?
I could review  and filter it so my translators can work with nice list but not with alien looking XML file.

Answer (score 2):

I made a custom shell script which tries to figure out the values needed. You can then use the [localize.py](http://www.stevestreeting.com/2010/05/18/os-x-localisation-incremental-genstrings-and-utf-8-files/) script in a modified way (see below) to automatically create the translation files. (The line break where somehow very important) If there more entities to be translated, the shell script can be modified accordingly

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f $2

sed -n 'N;/<key>Title<\/key>/{N;/<string>.*<\/string>/{s/.*<string>\(.*\)<\/string>.*/\/*     \1 *\/\
"\1" = "\1";\
/p;};}' $1 >> $2

sed -n 'N;/<key>FooterText<\/key>/{N;/<string>.*<\/string>/{s/.*<string>\(.*\)<\/string>.*/\/* \1 *\/\
\"\1" = "\1";\
/p;}
;}' $1 >> $2

sed -n 'N;/<key>Titles<\/key>/{N;/<array>/{:a
N;/<\/array>/!{
/<string>.*<\/string>/{s/.*<string>\(.*\)<\/string>.*/\/* \1 *\/\
\"\1" = "\1";\
/p;}
ba
;};};}' $1 >> $2
```

the localize.py script needed some modification. Therefore [I created a small package](https://github.com/gamma/Localize) containing the localizer for the source code and for the plist Files. The new script even supports Duplikates (meaning it will kick them)

Answer (score 1):

We recently made a small online application to do that, please take a look on: http://www.icapps.be/plist-translator/

Comment: The online app doesn't seem to be available anymore, is there a new location?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any command off the top of my head. However, plists are glorified xml files and there are various parsers available for them.

It shouldn't be too difficult to create a simple python script to get all the strings from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?
http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/how-to-translate-plist-files/

We much prefer paying clients who use our translation system with our translators, but you can translate yourself in our GUI at no charge.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to translate plists. I already have a native translation team. I only need to prepare list of strings for them.